# Is it possible to specify a default WOPI host for Office Online Server?

Tags: ms-wopi, office-online-server

Is there a way to specify a default WOPI host for Office Online Server (local installation, not cloud), so that the domain part in `WOPISrc` param can be omitted?

I am building a host page that uses an iframe to display the Online Office editor, and it bugs me that WOPI host information is exposed as the `WOPISrc` param of the iframe source URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. From this perspective, OOS works in a kinda stateless fashion.

And even if there was a way, the URL couldn't be truly protected...obscured perhaps, but not protected.